# Automatically return autocomplete selector option as selected

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using a form autofill plugin that uses the Google Maps API to autocomplete a WooCommerce checkout form. One snag that it has is that it doesn't autoselect the state in the select dropdown. If you manually click the select dropdown, you see that the plugin has highlighted the correct state in the dropdown options, but it doesn't automatically return that state as selected in the State / County selector. This then causes a further snag in that if you then manually click the state option that is highlighted, that state won't populate as selected.

In the image I show what the code is doing. It's not returning the option as selected and then if you click on the dropdown, it has the state highlighted but hasn't returned it as selected.

[image]

I have looked at the JS for this plugin and I'm not seeing where the problem lies, although it's likely related to billing_state. Is there any way to force this code to return the highlighted option as selected instead of just highlighting it?

```
var Cas_billing = Cas_billing || {},
    Cas_shipping = Cas_shipping || {};
if (Cas_billing.event = {}, Cas_shipping.event = {}, Cas_billing.method = {
        searchAddress: "",
        seprateIds: "",
        sugessions: "",
        streetNumber: "",
        formFields: {
            billing_address_1: "",
            billing_address_2: "",
            billing_city: "",
            billing_state: "",
            billing_postcode: "",
            billing_country: ""
        },
        formFieldsValue: {
            billing_address_1: "",
            billing_address_2: "",
            billing_city: "",
            billing_state: "",
            billing_postcode: "",
            billing_country: ""
        },
        component_form: "",
        initialize: function() {
            this.getseprateIds(), this.initFormFields(), this.sugessions = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("billing_address_1"), {
                types: ["geocode"]
            }), google.maps.event.addListener(this.sugessions, "place_changed", function() {
                Cas_billing.method.fillInAddress()
            });
            var e = document.getElementById("billing_address_1");
            null != e && e.addEventListener("focus", function() {
                Cas_billing.method.setCurrentCountry()
            }, !0);
            var s = document.getElementById("billing_country");
            null != s && s.addEventListener("change", function() {
                Cas_billing.method.setCurrentCountry()
            }, !0)
        },
        getseprateIds: function() {
            return document.getElementById("billing_address_1") ? (this.seprateIds = ":", ":") : (this.seprateIds = "_", "_")
        },
        initFormFields: function() {
            for (var e in this.formFields) this.formFields[e] = e;
            this.component_form = {
                street_number: ["billing_address_1", "short_name"],
                route: ["billing_address_1", "long_name"],
                locality: ["billing_city", "long_name"],
                administrative_area_level_1: ["billing_state", "short_name"],
                country: ["billing_country", "long_name"],
                postal_code: ["billing_postcode", "short_name"]
            }
        },
        fillInAddress: function() {
            this.clearFormValues(), this.sugessions.setFields(["address_components"]);
            var e = this.sugessions.getPlace();
            for (var s in this.resetForm(), e.address_components)
                for (var t in e.address_components[s].types)
                    for (var n in this.component_form) {
                        if (n == e.address_components[s].types[t]) {
                            "street_number" == n ? this.streetNumber = e.address_components[s].short_name : "KR" == document.getElementById("billing_country").value && (this.streetNumber = e.address_components[0].short_name, this.streetNumber += "," + e.address_components[1].long_name);
                            var i = this.component_form[n][1];
                            e.address_components[s].hasOwnProperty(i) && (this.formFieldsValue[this.component_form[n][0]] = e.address_components[s][i])
                        }
                    }
            this.appendStreetNumber(), this.fillForm(), $ = jQuery.noConflict(), $("#billing_state").trigger("change"), "undefined" != typeof FireCheckout && checkout.update(checkout.urls.billing_address)
        },
        clearFormValues: function() {
            for (var e in this.formFieldsValue) this.formFieldsValue[e] = ""
        },
        appendStreetNumber: function() {
            "" != this.streetNumber && (this.formFieldsValue.billing_address_1 = this.streetNumber + " " + this.formFieldsValue.billing_address_1)
        },
        fillForm: function() {
            for (var e in this.formFieldsValue)
                if ("billing_country" == e) this.selectRegion(e, this.formFieldsValue[e]);
                else {
                    if (null === document.getElementById(e)) continue;
                    document.getElementById(e).value = this.formFieldsValue[e]
                }
        },
        selectRegion: function(e, s) {
            if (null == document.getElementById(e)) return !1;
            for (var t = document.getElementById(e), n = 0; n < t.options.length; n++)
                if (t.options[n].text == s) {
                    t.selectedIndex = n;
                    break
                }
        },
        resetForm: function() {
            null !== document.getElementById("billing_address_2") && (document.getElementById("billing_address_2").value = "")
        },
        setCurrentCountry: function() {
            if (null === document.getElementById("billing_country")) e = "US";
            else var e = document.getElementById("billing_country").value;
            this.sugessions.setComponentRestrictions({
                country: e
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: this code is not readable and we'll not try to decode it, you should clarify your question

Comment: What is it that you would like clarified? And who is this we you speak of?

Comment: Hi @VAnton, he means that it would be appreciated if you could format the question little bit so that we can comprehend it easily. It will help both us save some time.

Comment: @Knick Oh sorry, didn't notice the code was wrapping like that. I've cleaned it up!